# Create focalMat for circular hectare when crs is in USfeet and SpatRast resolution is 10m

Tags: terra

I'm trying to create a raster using the `focal()` function that calculates the sum of forested non-zero binary pixels within a circular hectare for a large forested area. The SpatRaster resolution is 32.8084 ft (aka 10m), and NAs exist.

```
library(terra)

#raster dimensions and crs
w <- round(2210 * 32.8084)# reproducing dimensions and resolution
h <- round(1829 * 32.8084)
ext <- c(0, w, 0, h)
crs <- "EPSG:2261" #UTM ... in feet.....
res <- 32.8084 # 10m in feet
num_rows <- ceiling(h / res)
num_cols <- ceiling(w / res)

#raster creation
forest <- rast(nrows = num_rows, ncols = num_cols, ext = ext, crs = crs, res = res)

#add random height values between 0 and 41
set.seed(123)
forest[] <- runif(ncell(forest), min = 0, max = 41)

#add some interesting chunks of forest/non-forest
forest[100:500, 100:500] <- 0
forest[200:750, 500:900] <- 0
forest[800:900, 1200:1700] <- 0
forest[1400:1500, 1700:1800] <- 0
forest[400:900, 1000:1200] <- 41 #all tall stuff
forest[1200:1300, 1700:1800] <- 41
forest[1600:1700, 2000:2100] <- 41
forest[300:870, 1600:1800] <- 41

#add some NA's, vernal pools or something
num_cells <- ncell(forest)
sample_indices <- sample(num_cells, 2500, replace = TRUE)
forest[sample_indices] <- NA
```

create binary raster of forest and "non-forest" bushes < 4m

```
threshold <- 4 # Z in meters.. X Y is in feet............... 
forest <- forest > threshold 
forest<- as.numeric(forest)
forest[forest == 1] <- 100 #1 pixel 10m = 100sqm
plot(forest)
```

he crux ..calculating forested area in sqm / hectare from circular radius

```
r <- rast(ncols =12, nrow =12, xmin = 0, crs = crs(forest)) 
radius <- sqrt(10000 / pi) * 3.28084 #feet aka 56.41897m 
fw <- focalMat(r, radius, type = "circle")
forest_ha <- terra::focal(x = forest, w = fw, fun = sum, na.policy="omit", na.rm = TRUE, expand =TRUE)
plot(forest_ha)
```

output scale is 0 to 100, this isn't a sum of all pixels surrounding cell. How can I verify 1 circular hectare is correctly calculated for each pixel?

I don't trust the outputs. Should my matrix dimensions be 12 X 12 or should I resample my input raster to 11.28m and set the matrix to 10 X 10 for more accurate per hectare calculations? Perhaps there are some initial steps I'm missing to get at what I'm trying to accomplish given the crs and resolution of my data. I'd also like to have my output on a scale that makes sense, since it's currently 0 to 100. Can I simply multiply by 100 to scale it to 10,000sqm?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question so that your R code becomes a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible, example*. That is, create some example data with code, or use a file that ships with R. Since we do not have `chm_10` (and we do not want to have to download it) it is not possible to understand your code or suggest alternatives. For examples see the R help files and most R questions on this site. A good starting point could be `?terra::focal`

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thank you. I've updated my code to make it reproducible, and did away with the `chm_10` object. Let me know if any further clarification is needed. Alternative way to interpret my question: On the outside chance my code is correct, how do I check that it's working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the focal mean, not the sum. The mean is not biased by `NA`s whereas the sum will always get lower in when there are `NA`s.

I would do this

```
fw <- focalMat(forest, radius, type = "circle")
fw[fw>0] <- 1

forest_ha <- terra::focal(x = forest, w=fw, fun=mean, 
               na.policy="omit", na.rm = TRUE, expand =TRUE)
```

You can check any cell like this

```
cell <- 2519978
a <- adjacent(forest, cell, fw) 
colMeans(forest[a[1,]], na.rm=TRUE)
#   lyr.1 
#95.87629 
forest_ha[cell]
#  focal_mean
#1   95.87629
```

This is the mean score for the focal window. To get the sum per ha, you can adjust it by multiplying it with 100.

Comment: Thank you! I had read about the issues regarding sum and NA's on a different thread, but had a bit of tunnel vision getting to my desired outcome.  Thank you for looking over my code, I really appreciate it!